# Drawing a nice looking Laser (Star Wars) on the canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Im currently in the process of animation some laser effects on the canvas for the purpose of making my game a bit more enjoyable.

For the purpose of that, i require the drawing and animation of "laser" weapons fire, something along the lines of Star Wars.

So far, im basicly only drawing a short line in red or blue and then drawing a thinner, white, line on top of it, so it gives the impression of a gradient.
I also use linecap = "round";

my current code:

```
function drawProjectile(weapon, ox, oy, x, y){
    var trailEnd = getPointInDirection(weapon.projSize*-2, getAngleFromTo({x: ox, y: oy}, {x: x, y: y}), x, y);

    fxCtx.lineCap = "round";

    fxCtx.beginPath(); //the background, wider beam
    fxCtx.moveTo(x+cam.o.x, y+cam.o.y);
    fxCtx.lineTo(trailEnd.x+cam.o.x, trailEnd.y+cam.o.y);
    fxCtx.closePath();
    fxCtx.strokeStyle = weapon.animColor //blue or red
    fxCtx.lineWidth = weapon.projSize;
    fxCtx.stroke();

    fxCtx.globalAlpha = 0.5; // the inner, thin, white beam
    fxCtx.strokeStyle = "white";
    fxCtx.lineWidth = 2;
    fxCtx.stroke();

    fxCtx.globalAlpha = 1;
    fxCtx.lineCap = "butt"; 
}
```

Can someone advice how to improve my laser beam effect ?

Comment: Use `ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "lighter"` its just as quick as "source-over" and adds to pixel  brightness. Great for laser , explosions, fire, lights, and your imagination. You should also pre render all your line objects and blurs and using stroke and fill is very very slow compared to drawing bitmaps or from off screen canvases. Also use `ctx.globalAlpha` to set the transparency of your FX.This may give you some additional ideas.. https://codepen.io/Blindman67/pen/zrjXqd

Comment: What do mean about pre-rendering ?
Do you mean that instead of using the canvas to create Beams, i should create a beam.png and use drawImage() ?

Comment: You can create them as images (png) and load them at start, or draw them on offscreen canvas. You can then draw them using ctx.drawImage

Comment: Thats very interesting. Thanks for the suggestion.
Can you explain to me how i can draw as drawImage() an element that is not a .png but was drawn manually on a different canvas, as you described it ?

Comment: If I get time tonight I will add it as an answer.

Comment: You can create a new canvas, draw complex shapes on it once.
```var osCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
osCanvas.width = 100;
osCanvas.height = 100;
var ctx = osCanvas.getContext('2d');          
// draw
```
and then paint this image each frame
`fxCtx.drawImage(titleCache, 0, 0);`
There are libraries that do all that stuff for you and make working with canvas easier

Comment: But there are other things that affect performance more, like using `fxCtx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)` instead of `canvas.width = canvas.width` and using `requestAnimationFrame` instead of `setTimeout`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Using canvas as images, glows, and more.

The demo below creates all the graphics it needs as offscreen canvases. The background is also drawn on to leave a burn mark when a laser hits the ground.

**Lasers**

Laser shots are 3 layered `ctx.drawImage` calls. The first 2 are glow with `ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "lighter"` . One has fixed alpha,  the second has a random alpha. The last is drawn `ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over"` and is just an image of a line.

There are 4 images (canvas) for the laaser called laserRed, laserGRed, laserGreen, and laserGGreen. the ones with the extra G are the laser glow.

When the laser shot is at the end I draw 4 frames of expanding glow from pre- rendered image. In the first of the 4 frames I draw to the background canvas leaving a burn mark.

**Pre rendered images**

All the graphics used are rendered in the function `onResize` which is called on resize from the boilerplate code.

The function `display` is called once every frame and handles all the animation.

There is an object called imageTools that has some helper functions to make the coding a little simplier. `var image = imageTools.createImage(width,height)` creates a canvas. The image has the context attached `image.ctx` so you can draw to it just like any canvas. You can then draw that image onto the global canvas with `imageTools.drawImage(image,x,y,scale,rotation,alpha)` The image is drawn at it center point with a scale, rotation, and alpha.

The bullets use an object pool so that the GC (Garbage collection) does not interfere to much.

I did not set any limits so those with high res devices or those with low end machines may see some slowdown. If its a problem OP you can reduce the bullet count by making them go a little faster, you can also reduce the rendering to just two or one layer. But this is a lot faster than if you were rendering with canvas vector calls, shadows, etc...

I will leave the rest for you to work out. Its a bit sparse in the comments but I did not have much time.

There is also some boilerplate at the bottom that is not very readable.

**Left click to start the war.**

```js
/*************************************************************************************
 * Called from boilerplate code and is debounced by 100ms 
 * Creates all the images used in the demo.
 ************************************************************************************/ 
var onResize = function(){                       
    // create a background as drawable image
    background = imageTools.createImage(canvas.width,canvas.height);
    // create tile image
    tile = imageTools.createImage(64,64);
    tile.ctx.fillStyle = imageTools.createGradient(ctx,"linear",0,0,64,64,["#555","#666"]);
    tile.ctx.fillRect(0,0,64,64); 
    tile.ctx.fillStyle = "#333"; // add colour
    tile.ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "lighter"; 
    tile.ctx.fillRect(0,0,62,2);
    tile.ctx.fillRect(0,0,2,62);
    tile.ctx.fillStyle = "#AAA"; // multiply colour to darken
    tile.ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "multiply"; 
    tile.ctx.fillRect(62,1,2,62);
    tile.ctx.fillRect(1,62,62,2);
    for(var y = -32; y < canvas.height; y += 64 ){
        for(var x = -32; x < canvas.width; x += 64 ){
            background.ctx.drawImage(tile,x,y);
        }
    }
    background.ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "multiply"; // setup for rendering burn marks

    burn = imageTools.createImage(flashSize/2,flashSize/2);
    burn.ctx.fillStyle = imageTools.createGradient(ctx,"radial",flashSize/4,flashSize/4,0,flashSize/4,["#444","#444","#333","#000","#0000"]);
    burn.ctx.fillRect(0,0,flashSize/2,flashSize/2); 
    
    
    glowRed = imageTools.createImage(flashSize,flashSize);
    glowRed.ctx.fillStyle = imageTools.createGradient(ctx,"radial",flashSize/2,flashSize/2,0,flashSize/2,["#855F","#8000"]);
                                                    // #855F is non standard colour last digit is alpha
                                                    // 8,8 is ceneter 0 first radius 8 second
    glowRed.ctx.fillRect(0,0,flashSize,flashSize); 
    
    glowGreen = imageTools.createImage(flashSize,flashSize);
    glowGreen.ctx.fillStyle = imageTools.createGradient(ctx,"radial",flashSize/2,flashSize/2,0,flashSize/2,["#585F","#0600"]);
                                                    // #855F is non standard colour last digit is alpha
                                                    // 8,8 is ceneter 0 first radius 8 second
    glowGreen.ctx.fillRect(0,0,flashSize,flashSize); 
    
    // draw the laser 
    laserLen = 32;
    laserWidth = 4;
    laserRed = imageTools.createImage(laserLen,laserWidth);
    laserGreen = imageTools.createImage(laserLen,laserWidth);
    laserRed.ctx.lineCap = laserGreen.ctx.lineCap = "round";
    laserRed.ctx.lineWidth = laserGreen.ctx.lineWidth = laserWidth;
    laserRed.ctx.strokeStyle = "#F33";
    laserGreen.ctx.strokeStyle = "#3F3";
    laserRed.ctx.beginPath();
    laserGreen.ctx.beginPath();
    laserRed.ctx.moveTo(laserWidth/2 + 1,laserWidth/2);
    laserGreen.ctx.moveTo(laserWidth/2 + 1,laserWidth/2);
    laserRed.ctx.lineTo(laserLen - (laserWidth/2 + 1),laserWidth/2);
    laserGreen.ctx.lineTo(laserLen - (laserWidth/2 + 1),laserWidth/2);
    laserRed.ctx.stroke();
    laserGreen.ctx.stroke();
    
    // draw the laser glow FX
    var glowSize = 8;
    laserGRed = imageTools.createImage(laserLen + glowSize * 2,laserWidth + glowSize * 2);
    laserGGreen = imageTools.createImage(laserLen + glowSize * 2,laserWidth + glowSize * 2);
    laserGRed.ctx.lineCap = laserGGreen.ctx.lineCap = "round";
    laserGRed.ctx.shadowBlur = laserGGreen.ctx.shadowBlur = glowSize;
    laserGRed.ctx.shadowColor = "#F33"
    laserGGreen.ctx.shadowColor = "#3F3";
    laserGRed.ctx.lineWidth = laserGGreen.ctx.lineWidth = laserWidth;
    laserGRed.ctx.strokeStyle = "#F33";
    laserGGreen.ctx.strokeStyle = "#3F3";
    laserGRed.ctx.beginPath();
    laserGGreen.ctx.beginPath();
    laserGRed.ctx.moveTo(laserWidth/2 + 1 + glowSize,laserWidth/2 + glowSize);
    laserGGreen.ctx.moveTo(laserWidth/2 + 1 + glowSize,laserWidth/2 + glowSize);
    laserGRed.ctx.lineTo(laserLen + glowSize * 2 - (laserWidth/2 + 1 + glowSize),laserWidth/2 + glowSize);
    laserGGreen.ctx.lineTo(laserLen + glowSize * 2 - (laserWidth/2 + 1 + glowSize),laserWidth/2 + glowSize);
    laserGRed.ctx.stroke();
    laserGGreen.ctx.stroke();
    
    
                           
    readyToRock = true;    
    
}
var flashSize = 16;
const flashBrightNorm = 4 * (flashSize/2) * (flashSize/2) * Math.PI; // area of the flash
var background,tile,glowRed,glowGreen,grad, laserGreen,laserRed,laserGGreen,laserGRed,readyToRock,burn;
readyToRock = false; 

/*************************************************************************************
 * create or reset a bullet
 ************************************************************************************/    
function createShot(x,y,xx,yy,speed,type,bullet){ // create a bullet object
    if(bullet === undefined){
        bullet = {};
    }
    var nx = xx-x; // normalise
    var ny = yy-y;
    var dist = Math.sqrt(nx*nx+ny*ny);
    nx /= dist;
    ny /= dist;
    bullet.x = x;
    bullet.y = y;
    bullet.speed = speed;
    bullet.type = type;
    bullet.xx = xx;
    bullet.yy = yy;
    bullet.nx = nx; // normalised vector
    bullet.ny = ny;
    bullet.rot =  Math.atan2(ny,nx); // will draw rotated so get the rotation 
    bullet.life = Math.ceil(dist/speed); // how long to keep alive

    return bullet;
}
// semi static array with object pool.
var bullets=[]; // array of bullets
var bulletPool=[]; // array of used bullets. Use to create new bullets this stops GC messing with frame rate
const BULLET_TYPES = {
    red : 0,
    green : 1,
}
/*************************************************************************************
 * Add a bullet to the bullet array
 ************************************************************************************/    
function addBullet(xx,yy,type){
    var bullet,x,y;
    if(bulletPool.length > 0){
        bullet = bulletPool.pop(); // get bullet from pool
    }
    if(type === BULLET_TYPES.red){
        x = canvas.width + 16 + 32 * Math.random();
        y = Math.random() * canvas.height;
    }else if(type === BULLET_TYPES.green){
        x = - 16 - 32 * Math.random();
        y = Math.random() * canvas.height;
    }
    // randomise shoot to position
    var r = Math.random() * Math.PI * 2;
    var d = Math.random() * 128 + 16;
    xx += Math.cos(r)* d;
    yy += Math.sin(r)* d;
    bullets[bullets.length] = createShot(x,y,xx,yy,16,type,bullet);
    
}
/*************************************************************************************
 * update and draw bullets
 ************************************************************************************/    
function updateDrawAllBullets(){
    var i,img,imgGlow;
    for(i = 0; i < bullets.length; i++){
        var b = bullets[i];
        b.life -= 1;
        if(b.life <= 0){ // bullet end remove it and put it in the pool
            bulletPool[bulletPool.length] = bullets.splice(i,1)[0];
            i--; // to stop from skipping a bullet
        }else{
            
            if(b.life < 5){
                if(b.life===4){
                    b.x += b.nx * b.speed * 0.5;  // set to front of laser 
                    b.y += b.ny * b.speed * 0.5;
                    var scale = 0.9 + Math.random() *1;
                    background.ctx.setTransform(scale,0,0,scale,b.x,b.y);
                    background.ctx.globalAlpha = 0.1 + Math.random() *0.2;;
                    background.ctx.drawImage(burn,-burn.width /2 ,-burn.height/2);
                }
                if(b.type === BULLET_TYPES.red){
                    img = glowRed;
                }else{
                    img = glowGreen;
                }
                ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "lighter"; 
                imageTools.drawImage(img,b.x,b.y,(4-b.life)*(4-b.life),b.rot,1);//b.life/4);                
                imageTools.drawImage(img,b.x,b.y,4,b.rot,b.life/4);                
                ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over"; 

                
            }else{
                b.x += b.nx * b.speed;
                b.y += b.ny * b.speed;
    
                if(b.type === BULLET_TYPES.red){
                    img = laserRed;
                    imgGlow = laserGRed;
                }else{
                    img = laserGreen;
                    imgGlow = laserGGreen;
                }
                ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "lighter"; 
                imageTools.drawImage(imgGlow,b.x,b.y,1,b.rot,1);
                imageTools.drawImage(imgGlow,b.x,b.y,2,b.rot,Math.random()/2);
                ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over"; 
                imageTools.drawImage(img,b.x,b.y,1,b.rot,1);
            }
        }
    }
    
    
}
/*************************************************************************************
 * Main display loop
 ************************************************************************************/
function display() { 
    if(readyToRock){
        ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0); // reset transform
        ctx.globalAlpha = 1; // reset alpha
        ctx.drawImage(background,0,0);
        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over"; 
        if(mouse.buttonRaw & 1){
            addBullet(mouse.x,mouse.y,BULLET_TYPES.red);
            addBullet(mouse.x,mouse.y,BULLET_TYPES.green);
        }
        updateDrawAllBullets();
    }
    
}

/*************************************************************************************
 * Tools for creating canvas images and what not
 ************************************************************************************/
var imageTools = (function () {
    // This interface is as is. No warenties no garenties, and NOT to be used comercialy
    var workImg,workImg1,keep; // for internal use
    var xdx,xdy,spr; // static vars for drawImage and drawSprite
    keep = false; 
    var tools = {
        canvas : function (width, height) {  // create a blank image (canvas)
            var c = document.createElement("canvas");
            c.width = width;
            c.height = height;
            return c;
        },
        createImage : function (width, height) {
            var i = this.canvas(width, height);
            i.ctx = i.getContext("2d");
            return i;
        },
        drawImage : function(image, x, y, scale, ang, alpha) {
            ctx.globalAlpha = alpha;
            xdx = Math.cos(ang) * scale;
            xdy = Math.sin(ang) * scale;
            ctx.setTransform(xdx, xdy, -xdy, xdx, x, y);
            ctx.drawImage(image, -image.width/2,-image.height/2);
        },
        hex2RGBA : function(hex){ // Not CSS colour as can have extra 2 or 1 chars for alpha
                                  // #FFFF & #FFFFFFFF last F and FF are the alpha range 0-F & 00-FF
            if(typeof hex === "string"){
                var str = "rgba(";
                if(hex.length === 4 || hex.length === 5){
                    str += (parseInt(hex.substr(1,1),16) * 16) + ",";
                    str += (parseInt(hex.substr(2,1),16) * 16) + ",";
                    str += (parseInt(hex.substr(3,1),16) * 16) + ",";
                    if(hex.length === 5){
                        str += (parseInt(hex.substr(4,1),16) / 16);
                    }else{
                        str += "1";
                    }
                    return str + ")";
                }
                if(hex.length === 7 || hex.length === 8){
                    str += parseInt(hex.substr(1,2),16) + ",";
                    str += parseInt(hex.substr(3,2),16) + ",";
                    str += parseInt(hex.substr(5,2),16) + ",";
                    if(hex.length === 5){
                        str += (parseInt(hex.substr(7,2),16) / 255).toFixed(3);
                    }else{
                        str += "1";
                    }
                    return str + ")";                
                }
                return "rgba(0,0,0,0)";
            }
        },            
        createGradient : function(ctx, type, x, y, xx, yy, colours){ // Colours MUST be array of hex colours NOT CSS colours
                                                                     // See this.hex2RGBA for details of format
            var i,g,c;
            var len = colours.length;
            if(type.toLowerCase() === "linear"){
                g = ctx.createLinearGradient(x,y,xx,yy);
            }else{
                g = ctx.createRadialGradient(x,y,xx,x,y,yy);
            }
            for(i = 0; i < len; i++){
                c = colours[i];
                if(typeof c === "string"){
                    if(c[0] === "#"){
                        c = this.hex2RGBA(c);
                    }
                    g.addColorStop(Math.min(1,i / (len -1)),c); // need to clamp top to 1 due to floating point errors causes addColorStop to throw rangeError when number over 1
                }
            }
            return g;
            
        },
    };
    return tools;
})();



// CODE FROM HERE DOWN IS SUPPORT CODE AN HAS LITTLE TO DO WITH THE ANSWER




//==================================================================================================
// The following code is support code that provides me with a standard interface to various forums.
// It provides a mouse interface, a full screen canvas, and some global often used variable
// like canvas, ctx, mouse, w, h (width and height), globalTime
// This code is not intended to be part of the answer unless specified and has been formated to reduce
// display size. It should not be used as an example of how to write a canvas interface.
// By Blindman67
if(typeof onResize === "undefined"){
    window["onResize"] = undefined;  // create without the JS parser knowing it exists.
                                     // this allows for it to be declared in an outside 
                                     // modal.
}
const RESIZE_DEBOUNCE_TIME = 100;
var w, h, cw, ch, canvas, ctx, mouse, createCanvas, resizeCanvas, setGlobals, globalTime = 0, resizeCount = 0;
createCanvas = function () {
    var c,
    cs;
    cs = (c = document.createElement("canvas")).style;
    cs.position = "absolute";
    cs.top = cs.left = "0px";
    cs.zIndex = 1000;
    document.body.appendChild(c);
    return c;
}
resizeCanvas = function () {
    if (canvas === undefined) {
        canvas = createCanvas();
    }
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth-2;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight-2;
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    if (typeof setGlobals === "function") {
        setGlobals();
    }
    if (typeof onResize === "function") {
        resizeCount += 1;
        setTimeout(debounceResize, RESIZE_DEBOUNCE_TIME);
    }
}
function debounceResize() {
    resizeCount -= 1;
    if (resizeCount <= 0) {
        onResize();
    }
}
setGlobals = function () {
    cw = (w = canvas.width) / 2;
    ch = (h = canvas.height) / 2;
    mouse.updateBounds();
}
mouse = (function () {
    function preventDefault(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    var mouse = {
        x : 0,
        y : 0,
        w : 0,
        alt : false,
        shift : false,
        ctrl : false,
        buttonRaw : 0,
        over : false,
        bm : [1, 2, 4, 6, 5, 3],
        active : false,
        bounds : null,
        crashRecover : null,
        mouseEvents : "mousemove,mousedown,mouseup,mouseout,mouseover,mousewheel,DOMMouseScroll".split(",")
    };
    var m = mouse;
    function mouseMove(e) {
        var t = e.type;
        m.x = e.clientX - m.bounds.left;
        m.y = e.clientY - m.bounds.top;
        m.alt = e.altKey;
        m.shift = e.shiftKey;
        m.ctrl = e.ctrlKey;
        if (t === "mousedown") {
            m.buttonRaw |= m.bm[e.which - 1];
        } else if (t === "mouseup") {
            m.buttonRaw &= m.bm[e.which + 2];
        } else if (t === "mouseout") {
            m.buttonRaw = 0;
            m.over = false;
        } else if (t === "mouseover") {
            m.over = true;
        } else if (t === "mousewheel") {
            m.w = e.wheelDelta;
        } else if (t === "DOMMouseScroll") {
            m.w = -e.detail;
        }
        if (m.callbacks) {
            m.callbacks.forEach(c => c(e));
        }
        if ((m.buttonRaw & 2) && m.crashRecover !== null) {
            if (typeof m.crashRecover === "function") {
                setTimeout(m.crashRecover, 0);
            }
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    m.updateBounds = function () {
        if (m.active) {
            m.bounds = m.element.getBoundingClientRect();
        }
    }
    m.addCallback = function (callback) {
        if (typeof callback === "function") {
            if (m.callbacks === undefined) {
                m.callbacks = [callback];
            } else {
                m.callbacks.push(callback);
            }
        } else {
            throw new TypeError("mouse.addCallback argument must be a function");
        }
    }
    m.start = function (element, blockContextMenu) {
        if (m.element !== undefined) {
            m.removeMouse();
        }
        m.element = element === undefined ? document : element;
        m.blockContextMenu = blockContextMenu === undefined ? false : blockContextMenu;
        m.mouseEvents.forEach(n => {
            m.element.addEventListener(n, mouseMove);
        });
        if (m.blockContextMenu === true) {
            m.element.addEventListener("contextmenu", preventDefault, false);
        }
        m.active = true;
        m.updateBounds();
    }
    m.remove = function () {
        if (m.element !== undefined) {
            m.mouseEvents.forEach(n => {
                m.element.removeEventListener(n, mouseMove);
            });
            if (m.contextMenuBlocked === true) {
                m.element.removeEventListener("contextmenu", preventDefault);
            }
            m.element = m.callbacks = m.contextMenuBlocked = undefined;
            m.active = false;
        }
    }
    return mouse;
})();

// Clean up. Used where the IDE is on the same page.
var done = function () {
    window.removeEventListener("resize", resizeCanvas)
    mouse.remove();
    document.body.removeChild(canvas);
    canvas = ctx = mouse = undefined;
}

resizeCanvas();
mouse.start(canvas, true);
mouse.crashRecover = done;
window.addEventListener("resize", resizeCanvas);

function update(timer) { // Main update loop
    globalTime = timer;
    display(); // call demo code
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
}
requestAnimationFrame(update);
/** SimpleFullCanvasMouse.js end **/
```

Comment: Holy shit. Thats quite something. Thank you so much for the input.

Comment: Hi @Blindman67 : can you help me understand the following animation? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52240261/canvas-impulse-animation-effect

Comment: Is there any way how to conveniently copy this code into Ide or codesandbox? there are interesting things here so I wanted to look into it outside of SO's sandbox modal, and first thing I get if it gets imported into html is - laserLen is not defined

Comment: @Jarek Sorry this code was written fast and dirty. Running it in strict mode is very likely to find many undeclared variables (as in `laserLen`). Code is over 7 years old, I will can not be bothered updating it.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a shadow for a glowing effect

```
fxCtx.shadowBlur = 10;
fxCtx.shadowColor = '#FD0100';
```

but i think thats all, bacause your laser is so small that a real gradient would not make sense.
Use some nice colors like #FEF1BA insted of white for the red laser and thats it