# Canvas Impulse Animation Effect

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, canvas

I'm studying the following canvas animation by Matei Copot. 
Can someone explain how the "impulse"/shooting effect works, and how, say I can simplify the code to only have 3 stationary dots a, b, and c (while showing the impulse effect between a-> b and between b -> c)?

```js
var w = c.width = window.innerWidth,
  h = c.height = window.innerHeight,
  ctx = c.getContext( '2d' ),
  
  opts = {
   
   range: 180,
   baseConnections: 3,
   addedConnections: 5,
   baseSize: 5,
   minSize: 1,
   dataToConnectionSize: .4,
   sizeMultiplier: .7,
   allowedDist: 40,
   baseDist: 40,
   addedDist: 30,
   connectionAttempts: 100,
   
   dataToConnections: 1,
   baseSpeed: .04,
   addedSpeed: .05,
   baseGlowSpeed: .4,
   addedGlowSpeed: .4,
   
   rotVelX: .003,
   rotVelY: .002,
   
   repaintColor: '#111',
   connectionColor: 'hsla(200,60%,light%,alp)',
   rootColor: 'hsla(0,60%,light%,alp)',
   endColor: 'hsla(160,20%,light%,alp)',
   dataColor: 'hsla(40,80%,light%,alp)',
   
   wireframeWidth: .1,
   wireframeColor: '#88f',
   
   depth: 250,
   focalLength: 250,
   vanishPoint: {
    x: w / 2,
    y: h / 2
   }
  },
  
  squareRange = opts.range * opts.range,
  squareAllowed = opts.allowedDist * opts.allowedDist,
  mostDistant = opts.depth + opts.range,
  sinX = sinY = 0,
  cosX = cosY = 0,
  
  connections = [],
  toDevelop = [],
  data = [],
  all = [],
  tick = 0,
  totalProb = 0,
  
  animating = false,
  
  Tau = Math.PI * 2;

ctx.fillStyle = '#222';
ctx.fillRect( 0, 0, w, h );
ctx.fillStyle = '#ccc';
ctx.font = '50px Verdana';
ctx.fillText( 'Calculating Nodes', w / 2 - ctx.measureText( 'Calculating Nodes' ).width / 2, h / 2 - 15 );

window.setTimeout( init, 4 ); // to render the loading screen

function init(){
 
 connections.length = 0;
 data.length = 0;
 all.length = 0;
 toDevelop.length = 0;
 
 var connection = new Connection( 0, 0, 0, opts.baseSize );
 connection.step = Connection.rootStep;
 connections.push( connection );
 all.push( connection );
 connection.link();
 
 while( toDevelop.length > 0 ){
 
  toDevelop[ 0 ].link();
  toDevelop.shift();
 }
 
 if( !animating ){
  animating = true;
  anim();
 }
}
function Connection( x, y, z, size ){
 
 this.x = x;
 this.y = y;
 this.z = z;
 this.size = size;
 
 this.screen = {};
 
 this.links = [];
 this.probabilities = [];
 this.isEnd = false;
 
 this.glowSpeed = opts.baseGlowSpeed + opts.addedGlowSpeed * Math.random();
}
Connection.prototype.link = function(){
 
 if( this.size < opts.minSize )
  return this.isEnd = true;
 
 var links = [],
   connectionsNum = opts.baseConnections + Math.random() * opts.addedConnections |0,
   attempt = opts.connectionAttempts,
   
   alpha, beta, len,
   cosA, sinA, cosB, sinB,
   pos = {},
   passedExisting, passedBuffered;
 
 while( links.length < connectionsNum && --attempt > 0 ){
  
  alpha = Math.random() * Math.PI;
  beta = Math.random() * Tau;
  len = opts.baseDist + opts.addedDist * Math.random();
  
  cosA = Math.cos( alpha );
  sinA = Math.sin( alpha );
  cosB = Math.cos( beta );
  sinB = Math.sin( beta );
  
  pos.x = this.x + len * cosA * sinB;
  pos.y = this.y + len * sinA * sinB;
  pos.z = this.z + len *        cosB;
  
  if( pos.x*pos.x + pos.y*pos.y + pos.z*pos.z < squareRange ){
  
   passedExisting = true;
   passedBuffered = true;
   for( var i = 0; i < connections.length; ++i )
    if( squareDist( pos, connections[ i ] ) < squareAllowed )
     passedExisting = false;

   if( passedExisting )
    for( var i = 0; i < links.length; ++i )
     if( squareDist( pos, links[ i ] ) < squareAllowed )
      passedBuffered = false;

   if( passedExisting && passedBuffered )
    links.push( { x: pos.x, y: pos.y, z: pos.z } );
   
  }
  
 }
 
 if( links.length === 0 )
  this.isEnd = true;
 else {
  for( var i = 0; i < links.length; ++i ){
   
   var pos = links[ i ],
     connection = new Connection( pos.x, pos.y, pos.z, this.size * opts.sizeMultiplier );
   
   this.links[ i ] = connection;
   all.push( connection );
   connections.push( connection );
  }
  for( var i = 0; i < this.links.length; ++i )
   toDevelop.push( this.links[ i ] );
 }
}
Connection.prototype.step = function(){
 
 this.setScreen();
 this.screen.color = ( this.isEnd ? opts.endColor : opts.connectionColor ).replace( 'light', 30 + ( ( tick * this.glowSpeed ) % 30 ) ).replace( 'alp', .2 + ( 1 - this.screen.z / mostDistant ) * .8 );
 
 for( var i = 0; i < this.links.length; ++i ){
  ctx.moveTo( this.screen.x, this.screen.y );
  ctx.lineTo( this.links[ i ].screen.x, this.links[ i ].screen.y );
 }
}
Connection.rootStep = function(){
 this.setScreen();
 this.screen.color = opts.rootColor.replace( 'light', 30 + ( ( tick * this.glowSpeed ) % 30 ) ).replace( 'alp', ( 1 - this.screen.z / mostDistant ) * .8 );
 
 for( var i = 0; i < this.links.length; ++i ){
  ctx.moveTo( this.screen.x, this.screen.y );
  ctx.lineTo( this.links[ i ].screen.x, this.links[ i ].screen.y );
 }
}
Connection.prototype.draw = function(){
 ctx.fillStyle = this.screen.color;
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.arc( this.screen.x, this.screen.y, this.screen.scale * this.size, 0, Tau );
 ctx.fill();
}
function Data( connection ){
 
 this.glowSpeed = opts.baseGlowSpeed + opts.addedGlowSpeed * Math.random();
 this.speed = opts.baseSpeed + opts.addedSpeed * Math.random();
 
 this.screen = {};
 
 this.setConnection( connection );
}
Data.prototype.reset = function(){
 
 this.setConnection( connections[ 0 ] );
 this.ended = 2;
}
Data.prototype.step = function(){
 
 this.proportion += this.speed;
 
 if( this.proportion < 1 ){
  this.x = this.ox + this.dx * this.proportion;
  this.y = this.oy + this.dy * this.proportion;
  this.z = this.oz + this.dz * this.proportion;
  this.size = ( this.os + this.ds * this.proportion ) * opts.dataToConnectionSize;
 } else 
  this.setConnection( this.nextConnection );
 
 this.screen.lastX = this.screen.x;
 this.screen.lastY = this.screen.y;
 this.setScreen();
 this.screen.color = opts.dataColor.replace( 'light', 40 + ( ( tick * this.glowSpeed ) % 50 ) ).replace( 'alp', .2 + ( 1 - this.screen.z / mostDistant ) * .6 );
 
}
Data.prototype.draw = function(){
 
 if( this.ended )
  return --this.ended; // not sre why the thing lasts 2 frames, but it does
 
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.strokeStyle = this.screen.color;
 ctx.lineWidth = this.size * this.screen.scale;
 ctx.moveTo( this.screen.lastX, this.screen.lastY );
 ctx.lineTo( this.screen.x, this.screen.y );
 ctx.stroke();
}
Data.prototype.setConnection = function( connection ){
 
 if( connection.isEnd )
  this.reset();
 
 else {
  
  this.connection = connection;
  this.nextConnection = connection.links[ connection.links.length * Math.random() |0 ];
  
  this.ox = connection.x; // original coordinates
  this.oy = connection.y;
  this.oz = connection.z;
  this.os = connection.size; // base size
  
  this.nx = this.nextConnection.x; // new
  this.ny = this.nextConnection.y;
  this.nz = this.nextConnection.z;
  this.ns = this.nextConnection.size;
  
  this.dx = this.nx - this.ox; // delta
  this.dy = this.ny - this.oy;
  this.dz = this.nz - this.oz;
  this.ds = this.ns - this.os;
  
  this.proportion = 0;
 }
}
Connection.prototype.setScreen = Data.prototype.setScreen = function(){
 
 var x = this.x,
   y = this.y,
   z = this.z;
 
 // apply rotation on X axis
 var Y = y;
 y = y * cosX - z * sinX;
 z = z * cosX + Y * sinX;
 
 // rot on Y
 var Z = z;
 z = z * cosY - x * sinY;
 x = x * cosY + Z * sinY;
 
 this.screen.z = z;
 
 // translate on Z
 z += opts.depth;
 
 this.screen.scale = opts.focalLength / z;
 this.screen.x = opts.vanishPoint.x + x * this.screen.scale;
 this.screen.y = opts.vanishPoint.y + y * this.screen.scale;
 
}
function squareDist( a, b ){
 
 var x = b.x - a.x,
   y = b.y - a.y,
   z = b.z - a.z;
 
 return x*x + y*y + z*z;
}

function anim(){
 
 window.requestAnimationFrame( anim );
 
 ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
 ctx.fillStyle = opts.repaintColor;
 ctx.fillRect( 0, 0, w, h );
 
 ++tick;
 
 var rotX = tick * opts.rotVelX,
   rotY = tick * opts.rotVelY;
 
 cosX = Math.cos( rotX );
 sinX = Math.sin( rotX );
 cosY = Math.cos( rotY );
 sinY = Math.sin( rotY );
 
 if( data.length < connections.length * opts.dataToConnections ){
  var datum = new Data( connections[ 0 ] );
  data.push( datum );
  all.push( datum );
 }
 
 ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'lighter';
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.lineWidth = opts.wireframeWidth;
 ctx.strokeStyle = opts.wireframeColor;
 all.map( function( item ){ item.step(); } );
 ctx.stroke();
 ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
 all.sort( function( a, b ){ return b.screen.z - a.screen.z } );
 all.map( function( item ){ item.draw(); } );
 
 /*ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
 ctx.arc( opts.vanishPoint.x, opts.vanishPoint.y, opts.range * opts.focalLength / opts.depth, 0, Tau );
 ctx.stroke();*/
}

window.addEventListener( 'resize', function(){
 
 opts.vanishPoint.x = ( w = c.width = window.innerWidth ) / 2;
 opts.vanishPoint.y = ( h = c.height = window.innerHeight ) / 2;
 ctx.fillRect( 0, 0, w, h );
});
window.addEventListener( 'click', init );
```

```css
canvas {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
}
```

```html
<canvas id=c></canvas>
<!--
ALGORITHM:

structure:
- gen( x,y,z ):
 - create node at x,y,z // blue
 - append some children to list:
  - within a certain distance to parent
  - outside a certain distance from any node
  - within a global distance
 - if no children
  - don't append any
  - set as end node // green-ish

- gen( 0,0,0 ) // red
- while list has items
 - gen( position of first item )
 - remove first item


impulse behaviour:
- pick( node ):
 - if node is end node
  - pick( original node )
 - else
  - pick( random node from node children )

- pick( original node)

-->
```

Comment: in the `opts`, changing `baseConnections` to `1` and `addedConnections` to `0` creates a single line. You can then make it so it only creates 3 nodes

Comment: either way, this is probably not a question for SO

Comment: @towc The man himself! Wow thank you so much! I tried playing with connectionsNum and 'attempt' to no avail. How do I, for example, make it so that the single line only creates 3 nodes? (The code is rather complicated and I'm still trying to understand)

Comment: @towc okay I hacked it by creating a counter and incrementing it before the links.push().